# Error - Not all code paths returns a value

Tags: c#

I start to programming C# and I try to fix a code but is give error 0f, not all code paths return a value one the first line "getOption()" and I don't understand why?
Is because the while without the while the code don't give an error.

```
        static int getOption()
    {
        // Declare variable to store user input
        int iOption = 0;

        while(iOption != 4)
        {
            // Display user options
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your option: ");
            Console.WriteLine("1. View Cit-E Cycling Locations ");
            Console.WriteLine("2. Register to participate ");
            Console.WriteLine("3. Display all registered participants ");
            Console.WriteLine("4. Exit ");

            // Get user input
            iOption = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            // Validate user input
            // It must be within the correct range
            while(iOption < 1 || iOption > 4)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid option between 1 and 4");
                iOption = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }

            // return validated option
            return iOption;
        }


    }
```

Comment: What do you think would happen if iOption starts as 4?

Comment: The error message literally tells you what's wrong. Look at your code, what will be returned if ```iOption``` is ```4```?

Comment: Place your `return iOption;` outside the while loop. You logic will process the iOption and one final value would be returned from the function.

Comment: an external program sets iOption  to 4 changing the value directly in ram. now what your function should do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to change the value of `iOption` to `4`(at least set breakpoint ant set up value). And for this case `getOption()` will not return anything.
You need to add `return iOption;` to the end of the method.

Answer (score 0):

You must assign value to iOption in order to avoid this error when number 4 is there.
Also , there is convention for method names in C#. **GetOption()** not **getOption**!